# php RecursiveDirectoryIterator show only folder and subfoldernames

Tags: php, performance

My site is getting slow and I found the isue:

this part here takes about 2/2.5 somtimes 3 seconds to load:

```
$root = 'assets/img/fotogalerij';
    $iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
    );

    $paths = array($root);
    unset($paths[0]);
    foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
        if ($dir->isDir()) {
            $paths[] = str_replace($root, '', $path);
        }
    }
```

I have about 2200 files in this directory 
and the *if ($dir->isDir())* part is the bottleneck.

Checking the isDir 2200 times kinda takes it toll

Is there a more efficient way to show only folder and subfoldernames?

I don't care about the files, I just want the folder and subfoldernames

I'm new to this area and the info I found regarding this issue, is about showing only the current folder names or list the filenames (like opendir, readdir, scandir, glob, etc.)

Comment: Applying `iterator_to_array`/`array_map("is_dir")` would avoid the interruptive within-loop isDir probing; but is unlikely to benefit performance significantly. Given a reasonably large folder structure, eschewing PHPs VM with `find . -type d` might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a field or database table holding the list of directories and subdirectories. Then setup a simple incrond ( http://inotify.aiken.cz ) task to execute a script that will add/remove items from that list every time something changes in the structure of the directory tree.

Effectively you will have a "cached" version of the directory/subdir list and it will be updated automatically. As a nice thing, it is very easy to setup

Comment: I'll make a sql database table and create a function in the backend/CMS that fills the directory structure.